# ASP.Net Gridview paging of columns

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP gridview in my program to show the records of the employees. The data contains about 60 columns. I have converted the columns into rows using the following code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillGrid1()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub FillGrid1()
    Dim strUnit As String
    Dim intMonthYr As Integer
    strUnit = Session("Unit")
    intMonthYr = Session("MonthYr")
    objReports.Unit = strUnit
    objReports.ForMonth = intMonthYr
    ds = objReports.MonthlyPayBill

    Dim new_ds As New DataSet
    new_ds = FlipDataSet(ds)
    Dim my_DataView As DataView = new_ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    GridView1.DataSource = my_DataView
    GridView1.DataBind() 
End Sub
Public Function FlipDataSet(ByVal my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i))
        Next
        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)

            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next
        ds1.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds1
End Function
```

The 60 columns are placed as 60 rows and each person is represented as a column.There are about 50 person's record and  I want to go for paging in the columns to show 10 persons in each page rather than 10 field in the gridview.

Comment: I don't see where you are having problem. The pagination is not different than when employees are rows. You'll just have to transform the data every time.

Comment: When I m paging the gridview, then it is done for the rows not for the columns. I want paging for the record of employees which became column after transform